# XSD Schema that JAXB would find acceptable

Tags: xsd, jaxb

I have a REST XML response that has a chunk of data like this:

```
<tag>
  <total-pages type="integer">5</total-pages>
  <previous-page nil="true"></previous-page>
  <next-page nil="true"></next-page>
  <offset type="integer">5</offset>
</tag>
```

Now, sometimes the data can come back like this:

```
<tag>
  <total-pages type="integer">5</total-pages>
  <previous-page type="integer">0</previous-page>
  <next-page type="integer">1</next-page>
  <offset type="integer">5</offset>
</tag>
```

I have been trying to come up with a XSD schema structure that will account for both possibilities that would be acceptable to JAXB.

I have tried:

```
<tag>
  <total-pages type="numeric-type" />
  <previous-page type="numeric-type" />
  <next-page type="numeric-type" />
  <offset type="numeric-type" />
</tag>

<xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:integer">
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:string" name="type" use="optional">
            <xsd:attribute type="xsd:boolean" name="nil" use="optional">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

but JAXB blows up with an unmarshalling error.

Thoughts on what XSD schema structure I could use to account for the variability in the returning XML (I cannot change the XML, it is coming from a third-party which I have no control).

Thank you,

Perry

Comment: What unmarshalling error do you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've started by generating one XSD from your XML samples (two in your case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module (http://www.paschidev.com)-->
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="tag">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="total-pages">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedByte">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="previous-page">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute name="nil" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="next-page">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="optional" />
                <xs:attribute name="nil" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="offset">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
              <xs:extension base="xs:unsignedByte">
                <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" />
              </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

When you compare with your XSD, you'll notice the use of **string** instead of **integer** as the base type. Which explains why you have a problem with unmarshalling: an empty string is not a valid number.

If instead of "nil" you would get an xsi:nil attribute, the XSD would've been generated differently, i.e. it would've had nillable="true" for your elements.

Since you cannot change the XML, then you're stuck with the use of string; alternatively, you could create a union between an empty string and a numeric value... as to how that'll look in JAXB, you can try it...

Comment: That seemed to do the trick.  As the material would be integer if data did come back, I was thinking integer rather than string.